# Dropped packets normal? How to solve?

Tags: networking, wired-networking

I have recently had some issues with the network connection from my desktop PC. Initially I noticed that it was only connected at 100MB when it should be 1GB. Trying some different cables solved that. I do keep getting dropped packets though:

[image]

I have a ~1M cable going from my PC to a wall mounted network point. The cable from that network point goes directly to a network switch which then has about a 20cm cable to my router (A Google Nest Wifi).

If I ping my gateway from a raspberry Pi (in the same network cupboard as gateway, connected through same switch) there are no dropped packets.

I am thinking that a packet through a wired home network should never be dropped on the way to my gateway...

I have tried different cables including connecting desktop direct to the switch. Some fixes intermittently fix the issue.

I am thinking that it might be the network card? (intel and part of the motherboard).

2 questions.

- Am I correct in thinking that packets should never be dropped over a very low usage wired network?
- what would be my next step to diagnose? A new network card?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in thinking that packets should never be dropped over a very low usage wired network?

Generally, yes. Packet loss should only come from a) network overload i.e. congestion, or b) data corruption, i.e. packets thrown away because their checksum does not match. For good-quality Ethernet links, the latter should be practically zero.

If neither the network nor the target device are loaded, then it's likely that the packets are getting damaged somewhere along the way – bad wiring, bad "wall mounted network point" (whatever that is), the specific switch port gone bad, etc.

> Initially I noticed that it was only connected at 100MB when it should be 1GB. Trying some different cables solved that. I do keep getting dropped packets though:

Both the fact that you're losing some packets and the fact that your Ethernet card decided to only negotiate a lower speed<sup>1</sup> indicate a problem with the physical link itself. I'm guessing that swapping the cables did nothing useful at all and you got 1 Gbps this time purely by chance, and the actual problem is elsewhere.

---

<sup>1</sup> (I don't know the mechanism behind this. As far as I know, the negotiation according to standard *does not* involve measuring the link quality in any way. Yet, I have seen Ethernet cards from different manufacturers, on different operating systems, automagically drop down from 1G to 100M, or even from 100M to 10M, purely because the connection was unreliable at higher speed. So it's definitely a *thing*, possibly one of those manufacturer proprietary features.)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Swapping the cable did mean that I was getting 350MB on fast.com whereas previously (when negotiated at 100MB) I was only getting 90 from fast.com (internet speed test).
"wall mounted network point" is just a plug in my wall where I plug my network cable into.

Answer (score 0):

The IP *does not guarantee delivery of packets*.

- The cable can be broken or too long. Very long cables should be shielded to protect them from interfering with other devices. That is not probably your case.
- Check your connectors. Badly crimped connectors can produce such behavior.
- Some device drops ICMP Ping packets because they typically are not important. Network switch can drop “low priority” packets when there's other traffic. The network does not have to be “overloaded”. Short burst of packets can easily trigger this functionality.
- Network interface card has failed. This is quite rare but possible.

Try some software that supports ping using UDP. When there are no lost packets, some device is just dropping ICMP pings.